# How to find some specific records without using sub query in mysql

Tags: mysql, join

I have 2 tables in my database. Both of have approx 100M records.My first table uph contains order's details and another urs contains customer's details. Their structure is:

```
mysql> desc uph;
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| uid        | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| order_from | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> desc usr;
+---------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| uid     | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| profile | char(10) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Both table have data like this:

```
mysql> select * from usr;
+-----+----------+
| uid | profile  |
+-----+----------+
|   1 | in-store |
|   2 | ecom     |
|   3 | ecom     |
|   4 | in-store |
|   5 | ecom     |
+-----+----------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from uph;
+----+-----+------------+
| id | uid | order_from |
+----+-----+------------+
|  1 |   1 | in-store   |
|  2 |   2 | ecom       |
|  3 |   1 | ecom       |
|  4 |   4 | in-store   |
+----+-----+------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now, I want to find those users which have profile "ecom" and if they've done any purchase then order_from should only be "ecom". If not purchsed anything only having profile, still will be considered as an "ecom" user.

If any user purchased from ecom and In-store both, those will be excuded from results. Which means users should not have any relation with In-store.

So in the output of the query we'll have the result like:

```
+----+
| uid |
+-----+
|  2  |
|  3  |
|  5  |
+-----+
```

As both tables contains heavy data so I'm restricted to user sub-query. Please suggest how to do it without using sub-query.

Comment: Why does the output not include 3? uid 3 has an ecom profile and has made no purchases (same as 5).

Comment: Yes, 3 is in output. I updated the post. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a join and check the aggregated results for your criteria

```
select u.uid, u.profile
from usr u
left join uph p on u.uid = p.uid
where u.profile = 'ecom'
group by u.uid, u.profile
having sum(case when p.order_from = 'in-store' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

Comment: Thanks @M Khalid

Your query worked for me finally. Thanks a lot.